# UICollectionView scroll whole page

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have a `viewController` with some text and under it a `UICollectionView` (about 50% of the page).

My problem is that when I scroll on the `collectionView` just the cells are being scrolled and not the whole page (the text + the collection cells).

You can think about it like on Instagram profile page (half info half `collectionView`), when you scroll on Instagram everything is being scrolled and not just the collection cells.

Anyone knows how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: @Dopapp the Instagram profile page, not the home page

Comment: May I suggest using a UITableView? I find it more organized and still very versatile

Comment: @Dopapp A UITableView with a UICollectionView cell?

Comment: no, replacing the collectionView with a tableView. It's a personal preference.

Comment: @Dopapp But I need a collectionView

Comment: Oh, well never mind then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because your text/`UILabels` doesn't belong within the `UIScrollView` of your `UICollectionView`, thus it will not be scrolled when the `collectionView` is. You could create a `UICollectionViewCell` for your text, include it within your `collectionview` and expand the `collectionView` to fit the screen or use a `UICollectionViewController`

Answer (score 1):

Add the text content as separate cells on top of the *UICollectionView*.

Preferably, create a different section which would contain the cells with the top text.

Keep the *backgroundColor*/*backgroundImage* of these cells plain to give the effect that they are simply added as *UILabels* on a form. Doing so will also differentiate from the rest of the actual *UICollectionViewCells*.

Now, when you scroll the UICollectionView. It will give an effect that the text along with the cells are scrolled.

Comment: Isn't there a different way to do it? I don't think this solution is that good, too messy

Answer (score 1):

In Attribute inspector > Scroll View > check Paging enable